# New bookmark syn for Google Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, bookmarks

On the new Google Chrome **New Tab** page there is a link for the new _Extensions" page and next to it the *Bookmark sync* link which actually does not link to anywhere. I have been wishing for Chrome to integrate bookmarks better with the Google user account so I could have my organized bookmarks from any computer, but now that I see this new link *Bookmark sync* on the bottom of the **New Tab** page I am curious, is there a new bookmark sync feature for chrome now?

Answer (score 2):

The bookmark sync syncs to Google Toolbar bookmarks... ([details](http://googlesystem.blogspot.com/2009/08/sync-google-chrome-bookmarks.html)). Nice and all, but I had hoped it would be an option to at least use Google's Bookmark service too. Alas.

With the beta version of Chrome you can also look into using the [Xmarks extension](https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/ajpgkpeckebdhofmmjfgcjjiiejpodla). Good sign of 3rd party integration solving this challenge long-term.

Comment: +1 for consideration of the Google Bookmarks service.  I've been using hampr.com as an alternative for some time now.  It even has a FF (not Chrome) add-on.